# Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

while running a project in android studio 2.3.2 shows

> Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip'.

and project get stucked with a 
 *app_debugAndroidTestApkCopy*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to slow internet connection or interrupted synchronization process.
Ensure that you have a strong internet connection and sync(re-build) your project.